# I'm stuck on the "Show Applications" menu until shutdown

Tags: linux, fedora, gnome, bug

If I press Mega or click the "Show Applications" button, the Show Applications menu will open mostly as it's supposed to (I won't see my installed programs, but they appear when searched for); more importantly however, the Show Applications menu will never *close*.

Anything that would usually close Show Applications (ie. opening an application, pressing Mega again, focusing an application), simply won't.

The only way I've managed to close it, *is to do a shutdown* - obviously that is too impractical to consider a solution.

Until I figure out a way to fix this, I will be unable to use any program on my computer that isn't favorited (ignoring using the command line to open applications, as I wouldn't even know where to start there).

(Note: This is on Fedora Linux and the issue began after an update; I would tell you the specific version number if I knew it, but I don't know how to check that without the Show Applications menu.)

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this issue today.

As a temporary workaround, at the login screen I selected another desktop environment (e.g. Gnome classic or i3) and those don't exhibit the same behaviour.

You could try rolling back the gnome packages. Report back if you manage to resolve the issue.